# How to add labels when converting Image files to CSV?

Tags: python, csv

I was looking at the deep learning guide on Kaggle. I practiced with a few models with my test data stored in directories with the name of the label (ie TestData\Top and TestData\Bottom for training images to create a model that can tell the top vs the bottom of an item of interest).

However for this lesson for creating your own model (https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/deep-learning-from-scratch), the data needs to be stored in a CSV file with the first column as the label. I have this code which converts the images to grayscale and to a CSV file and grabs the labels:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
import sys
import os
import csv
import glob

from os import path

TestPath = 'C:\...\outgoingbank'

Labels = []
myFileList = []


for files in os.listdir(TestPath):
    Labels.append(files)
    os.chdir(TestPath)
    for images in os.listdir(files):
        fullName = os.path.join(files, images)
        myFileList.append(fullName)



print (Labels)
print(myFileList)


for file in myFileList:
   print(file)
   Label = file.split('\\')
   Label = Label[0]
   print (Label)
   img_file = Image.open(file)


    # get original image parameters...
    width, height = img_file.size
    format = img_file.format
    mode = img_file.mode

    # Make image Greyscale
    img_grey = img_file.convert('L')


    value = np.asarray(img_grey.getdata(), dtype=np.int).reshape((img_grey.size[1], img_grey.size[0]))
    value = value.flatten()
    print(value)
    with open("C:\...\img_pixels.csv", 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(value)
```

So I have the labels and the images, and code that converts the images to a CSV, but how would I insert the label into the first row? Also, is it possible to do not convert them to greyscale? (I tried but got a sizing error)

EDIT: I was able to add the labels via:

```
Test = []

Test.append(Label)
for i in value:
    Test.append(i)

#print(Test)
with open("C:\...\img_pixels.csv", 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(Test)
```

But I still don't see why this code is only writing to every other row, how do I fix that?

Comment: Can’t you just add the label when you do the `writerow()`?

Comment: I'm not sure how, I tried writerow(Label + value) and writerow(Label, value) and both yielded errors. I also tried value = Label + value and value = np.insert(value, 0, Label)

Comment: Have you read the docs for the csv library?

Comment: I did, but apparently not thoroughly enough. I tried Test = [Label, value], writerows(Test) and that seems to work, but it seems my code is only writing to every other row

Comment: In fact, this is writing one row where every letter of the label occupies its own cell, then a blank row, then value. Not quite what I was going for...back to the documentation...

Comment: Courage! You’re getting there.

Comment: can't you do `value.append(Label)` and `writerow(value)` instead of  using loop `for i in value: Test.append(i)` and `writerow(Test)`?`

Comment: do you mean you have empty lines in csv? Maybe you have new line `\n` in some text - you have to remove it before you write it.

Comment: I can't, 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'append'. And I tried value = np.insert(value, 0, Label)